# filter extension while checking folder path using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I have a code which check all the directories and sub-directories so while checking the directories and sub directories i want to check if the specific extension file is present or not if present then i want to filter them in two array

code i have to check all the files is

```js
async function checkFileLoc(folderPath, depth) {
  depth -= 1;
  let files = await fsPromises.readdir(folderPath);
  files = await Promise.all(
    files.map(async (file) => {
      const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
      const stats = await fsPromises.stat(filePath);
      if (stats.isDirectory() && depth > 0) {
        return checkFileLoc(filePath, depth);
      } else if (stats.isFile()) return filePath;
      else return null;
    })
  );
  return files
    .reduce((all, folderContents) => all.concat(folderContents), [])
    .filter((e) => e != null);
}
```

Code to check if the `.jpg` ext file present or not but its not working for me and i want to filter further.

```js
async function FilterFile(folderPath) {
  wantExt = [".jpg"];
  let  parts;
  const paths = await checkFileLoc(folderPath, 3);

  const otherFiles = [];
  
  for (const filePath of paths) {
    parts = filePath.split("/");
    let splitFileName = parts[parts.length - 1].split(".");
    if (wantExt.includes(`.${splitFileName[splitFileName.length - 1]}`)) {
      otherFiles.push(filePath);
    }
  }
  return { otherFiles };
}
```

I want to check if my location contain all the `.jpg` file or not if it contain then its should filter `_bio.jpg` and other `.jpg` files differently.

```
Output:
bioArr=
[ "animal_bio.jpg"
  "mammal_bio.jpg"
]
otherArr=
[ "tree_doc.jpg"
  "human.jpg"
  "flowes_info.jpg"
]
```

Comment: Instead personally parsing for file name and extension name, I'd suggest you use path. It comes natively in node and makes it easier to deal with windows forward slash file names. It also has a parse function that returns an object containing the root, dir, file name, and file extension https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let bioArray = paths.filter(x => x.endsWith("_bio.jpg"));
paths = paths.filter( x => !bioArray.includes(x)); //removing all bio items
let otherJpg = paths.filter(x => x.endsWith(".jpg"));
```